# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/time/MonoClock

Tags: kotlin, koin

I have recently updated the version of Kotlin to `1.3.70` in my Android project.

Since then `Koin` (version: `2.1.0-beta-1` ) is giving me the run time error below:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/time/MonoClock;`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Increasing the version of Koin to `2.1.3` solved the issue.